# Oriented angle of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, angle

I wonder how I can compute the oriented angle between 2 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

The dot product will provide me the value of the angle but not the orientation.

Hope someone would the able to enlighten me =)

Comment: Are you assuming that the two vectors are given as an **ordered** pair of vectors? If not, your question makes no sense, not even in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meaned, I'm sorry if it was a clumsy formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the determinant. If your ordered pair of vectors is $V = \langle a,b \rangle$ and $W = \langle c,d \rangle$ then you have a $+$ angle if $ad-bc>0$ and a $-$ angle if $ad-bc<0$.

However, there is no consistent way to do this in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $n \ge 3$. The reason for this is that what one is really measuring is distance on the $n-1$-dimensional sphere $S^{n-1}$. Distance, in general, is an unsigned quantity: it is always positive or zero; negative distance does not make sense.

The difference between $n \ge 3$ and $n=2$ is that $S^1$ is one-dimensional and it has a natural sense of "counter-clockwise orientation".

Comment: So you mean that orientation has no meaning with $n \ge 3$ ?

Comment: Orientation of a pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \ge 3$ has no meaning, that is correct. However, orientation of an ordered 3-tuple of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ certainly has meaning. More generally orientation of an ordered $n$-tuple of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ also has meaning: put those vectors as the rows of an $n \times n$ matrix and take the sign of the determinant.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your explanations and reactivity, you solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

Comment: I guess hyperspherical coordinates will provide me n-1 angles to describe the path between the 2 vectors, I'm rather looking for a single measure for the 2 vectors, like the one provided by the dot product method but without loosing the orientation information. Since cos(a, b) = cos(b, a), the information of orientation is lost, I wonder how I could retrieve it in Rn (it is possible with R2 and R3)

Comment: So I'm not sure that is what I need, but thanks for the suggestion!